# Move selected index when typing in a WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a problem with the combobox in WPF. You know that when you open the combobox and you start typing, that the selected index of the combobox is moving to the element that starts with the same letter. Well i actually need the same thing but a bit different.

The items in the combobox are actually binded to a class. This class has 2 properties, a Code property ( contains for example "XF15A") and a Description property ( contains for example "Radio"). I used a data template that actually binded the text for an combobox item to  "[code] - [Description]".

Now when the type "XF" is goes to the combobox item that starts "XF". But what i now also need is that when you type  "Ra" it should go to the combobox item "XF15A - Radio".

Do you guys know how to solve this? I'm also open for existing usercontrols.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

My code is not quite what you want, but should give you an example of how you could do it yourself:

You got to handle `PreviewTextInput` yourself and let your algorithm decide which item to select. Here's a simple example:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" PreviewTextInput="ComboBox_PreviewTextInput">
    <ComboBoxItem>adsfsf</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>adsfsf</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>acdd</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>adsfsf</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void ComboBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    cb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    foreach (ComboBoxItem item in cb.Items)
    {
        var str = (string)item.Content;
        if(str.Contains(e.Text))
        {
            cb.SelectedItem = item;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```